# Media Queries not respecting size

Tags: css, media-queries

I was curious what was going wrong here with my media queries. I just want one style for 'reasonably small screens' and one style for 'reasonably large screens'. So I did the following:

```
@media (min-width: 501px) {
    #courtName {
        font-size: 17px;
    }
    #courtInfoWindow {
        font-size: 13px;
    }
}

@media (max-width:500px) {
    #courtName {
        font-size: 64px;
    }
    #courtInfoWindow {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
}
```

I would expect the min width size to show on 'large screens' and the max width size to show on small screens (less than 500px). Yet, the smaller size is shown on all screen sizes. I've tried using just one media query to override a default size. Tried switching the order. Nothing is working. What gives?

Comment: Your media queries working fine, need more clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

before starting make sure you have following view port meta in your head section.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

After this
please note following

`@media (min-width: 501px) { /** CSS HERE **/ }`
 This will work only on screen size larger than 501 pixels wide.

`@media (max-width: 500px)`
 This will work only on screen sizes smaller than 500 pixels wide.

Comment: Ok so the meta tag completely destroys my mobile css haha. That must be the problem.

Comment: No. Meta tag is necessary for media queries to take change.

Comment: If you see any change on mobile after meta tag, then it means that your media queries were not taking effect as there was not meta tag on page. This meta tag forces screen to disable screen zoom, or scaling on lower screen sizes. After this, you will need to adjust your mobile/tablet layout.

Comment: The solution was a combination of the meta tag not being present and the fact that if you mask a dns with godaddy they put your app in a frame that destroys the mobile design.